# My absolute image needs to be responsive

Tags: html, image, css

I'm having trouble getting my image to be responsive.  It's a image that sits above another image, so I used absolute positioning.  If I make the page smaller, everything gets all out of whack.

This is my css for the image that sits above the other image.

```
.page-header .logo img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 240%;
   left: 126%;
   width: 200px;
   height: 150px;
   padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   background-color:#000;
   margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
}
```

And this is the css for the image behind it.

```
.page .carousel img {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

How can I make the above image to resize properly with the image behind it?

Comment: Can you JSFiddle us an example?

Comment: Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/9b332ghd/  When the page is resized, the top image doesn't stay in place, or shrink.

Comment: Fixed my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9b332ghd/1/  I forgot some css in the first one.  Now the background resizes.

Comment: What is the intended display? Should the smaller image be perfectly centered in the other image? What images should respond? How should they respond? Should they respond by changing overlay position, or should they respond by becoming smaller and scaling?

Comment: The problem, is that you are setting the `width` and `height` of the `.logo` img. It will never be responsive. Check out this fiddle to see what I did. Hopefully this gets you closer: http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/9b332ghd/2/

Comment: The smaller image perfect centered over the other image.  And they should respond like the back image. Resize, but resize together.

Comment: Just realized, I put the logo inside the carousel, which probably won't work. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little fiddle I put together to get you closer. Depending on the size of the logo, you'll have to adjust the percentages a little bit to get what you want.

**HTML**

```
<div class='page-header'>
    <div class='carousel' id='portfolio-carousel'>
        <img alt="1396051485478" src="http://www.placehold.it/650x350" class="bg" />
    </div>
    <div class="logo-wrap">
        <img alt="Logo" src="http://www.placehold.it/250x150" class="logo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page-header {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

.logo-wrap {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-43%;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    padding:1px;
    border:1px solid #021a40;
    background-color:#000;
    top:22%;
    left:25%;
    width:50%;

}

.carousel {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}


.bg {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/9b332ghd/4/

I believe this will get you what you are looking for. Also, I may have changed some of your class names while I was troubleshooting it for you.